# Logout doesn't work after updating Spring Boot from 2.7 to 3.0.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application and the web security config looks like as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = false)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // enables oauth2 login for any request
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2Login()
                // configures logout adding an oidc logout success handler and invalidating the session on logout
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                // adds security headers
                .and()
            .headers()
                .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Referrer-Policy", "same-origin"))
                .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"))
                // configures csrf
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(getCookieCsrfTokenRepository());
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        // disables security for swagger ui and open api docs
        return web -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**/health", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/**");
    }

    private CookieCsrfTokenRepository getCookieCsrfTokenRepository() {
        CookieCsrfTokenRepository cookieCsrfTokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
        cookieCsrfTokenRepository.setCookiePath("/");
        return cookieCsrfTokenRepository;
    }

    private OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        // configures the oidc logout success handler to redirect to the idp login page
        OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler successHandler = new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository);
        successHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("{baseUrl}" + RouteConstants.IDP_LOGIN);
        return successHandler;
    }
}
```

After updating the Spring Boot version from 2.7 to 3.0.1 and doing according changes, the applications runs normally I can login successfully, but the logout doesn't work. The `WebSecurityConfig` class now looks like as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = false)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // enables oauth2 login for any request
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2Login()
                // configures logout adding an oidc logout success handler and invalidating the session on logout
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                // adds security headers
                .and()
            .headers()
                .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Referrer-Policy", "same-origin"))
                .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"))
                // configures csrf
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(getCookieCsrfTokenRepository());
        return http.build();
    }

    //The rest of the methods are the same
}
```

I added this property to make paths starting with /** work in a method webSecurityCustomizer()

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
```

I noticed that the response cookie of http://localhost/api/v1/authentication/idp_login request doesn't contain XSRF-TOKEN, but before the update it was. Looking at the logs I am getting this error

```
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing POST /logout
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking CsrfFilter (5/15)
2023-01-21 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter - Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost/api/v1/authentication/logout

2023-01-21 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl - Responding with 403 status code
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/**/health'], Filters=[]] (1/4)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/swagger-ui/**'], Filters=[]] (2/4)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/v3/**'], Filters=[]] (3/4)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@527fc8e, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@61bfc9bf, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@3722c145, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7601bc96, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@33063f5b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3291b443, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@707b1a44, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter@7132a9dc, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@424de326, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@2c7106d9, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@2975a9e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@765ffb14, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@329bad59, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@33634f04, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@53abfc07]] (4/4)
2023-01-21 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing POST /error
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking CsrfFilter (5/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking LogoutFilter (6/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter - Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter (7/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter (8/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter - Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login/oauth2/code/*']
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter (9/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter (10/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (11/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache - matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (12/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (13/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (14/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (15/15)
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [f:5f27139d-e373-4f94-885e-2771b67c493e:admin], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=IezFNMq7qXBpS499wXpjZg, sub=f:5f27139d-e373-4f94-885e-2771b67c493e:admin, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:80/idp/realms/products, typ=ID, preferred_username=admin, nonce=RpXazbXIYWDYNmAYJeX088axKakz0J-XpIq7KoYzHGs, platform={userId=db1ca9cc-da2e-4e6a-bd96-111111111111, username=admin, email=admin@fortra.tmp.com, tenantId=bf045e23-d197-4ba2-ba5b-1f1f275ac2cd, cpUserId=cp_user_id2}, sid=9a579605-b6aa-4267-91e9-d6cfde2bbc4d, aud=[cp], acr=1, azp=cp, auth_time=2023-01-21T19:54:16Z, exp=2023-01-21T19:59:17Z, session_state=9a579605-b6aa-4267-91e9-d6cfde2bbc4d, iat=2023-01-21T19:54:26Z, jti=7278704f-2b56-471a-9b11-ef017268de23}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=172.27.0.11, SessionId=9fa00c79-63cf-4528-bf1f-c0d358d9b655], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]] from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [f:5f27139d-e373-4f94-885e-2771b67c493e:admin], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=IezFNMq7qXBpS499wXpjZg, sub=f:5f27139d-e373-4f94-885e-2771b67c493e:admin, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:80/idp/realms/products, typ=ID, preferred_username=admin, nonce=RpXazbXIYWDYNmAYJeX088axKakz0J-XpIq7KoYzHGs, platform={userId=db1ca9cc-da2e-4e6a-bd96-111111111111, username=admin, email=admin@fortra.tmp.com, tenantId=bf045e23-d197-4ba2-ba5b-1f1f275ac2cd, cpUserId=cp_user_id2}, sid=9a579605-b6aa-4267-91e9-d6cfde2bbc4d, aud=[cp], acr=1, azp=cp, auth_time=2023-01-21T19:54:16Z, exp=2023-01-21T19:59:17Z, session_state=9a579605-b6aa-4267-91e9-d6cfde2bbc4d, iat=2023-01-21T19:54:26Z, jti=7278704f-2b56-471a-9b11-ef017268de23}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=172.27.0.11, SessionId=9fa00c79-63cf-4528-bf1f-c0d358d9b655], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Did not re-authenticate OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [f:5f27139d-e373-4f94-885e-2771b67c493e:admin], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=IezFNMq7qXBpS499wXpjZg, sub=f:5f27139d-e373-4f94-885e-2771b67c493e:admin, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:80/idp/realms/products, typ=ID, preferred_username=admin, nonce=RpXazbXIYWDYNmAYJeX088axKakz0J-XpIq7KoYzHGs, platform={userId=db1ca9cc-da2e-4e6a-bd96-111111111111, username=admin, email=admin@fortra.tmp.com, tenantId=bf045e23-d197-4ba2-ba5b-1f1f275ac2cd, cpUserId=cp_user_id2}, sid=9a579605-b6aa-4267-91e9-d6cfde2bbc4d, aud=[cp], acr=1, azp=cp, auth_time=2023-01-21T19:54:16Z, exp=2023-01-21T19:59:17Z, session_state=9a579605-b6aa-4267-91e9-d6cfde2bbc4d, iat=2023-01-21T19:54:26Z, jti=7278704f-2b56-471a-9b11-ef017268de23}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=172.27.0.11, SessionId=9fa00c79-63cf-4528-bf1f-c0d358d9b655], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]] before authorizing
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorizing filter invocation [POST /error] with attributes [authenticated]
2023-01-21 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorized filter invocation [POST /error] with attributes [authenticated]
2023-01-21 TRACE org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Did not switch RunAs authentication since RunAsManager returned null
2023-01-21 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured POST /error
```

Do the other changes need to make it work?

Comment: Checkout https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-oidc-logout

Comment: When you say "the logout doesn't work" can you share more about what doesn't work? Can you share your TRACE logs (enable `logger.level.org.springframework.security=trace`)?

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg thanks for your replay. I am getting 403. Here is the lines from log 
org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter - Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost/api/v1/authentication/logout
org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl - Responding with 403 status code
TRACE org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
I want to mention that I added this in the application.properties file
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher

Comment: Correction to above comment, `logging.level...`.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by adding csrfTokenRequestHandler like this

```
    http.csrf().csrfTokenRequestHandler(getCsrfTokenRequestHandler())

    private CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler getCsrfTokenRequestHandler() {
        CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
        // set the name of the attribute the CsrfToken will be populated on
        requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName(null);
        return request handler;
    }
```

Still had another issue that **x-xss-protection** is 0 but should be **"1; mode=block"**

Comment: Yes, this is one possible way to resolve your issue, by disabling deferred csrf tokens. Note that this is documented in the [exploits](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html) section of the [5.8 migration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/index.html), which is hopefully where you found it. Note that we are recommending upgrading to 5.8 first, following steps in the migration guide, and only then upgrading to 6.0.